# XSD atttribute restriction failed

Tags: xml, xsd

We have issue with XSD (XML Scheme) and validation. Basically, we need to restrict attribute values defined in one complex type:

```
<xsd:element name="Modeling" type="CTypeRestric"/>
<xsd:complexType name="CTypeRestric">
<xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="CType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="c2">
            <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="C2BaseRest"/>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="c3">
            <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="C3BaseRest"/>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:simpleType name="C2BaseRest">
    <xsd:restriction base="C2Base">
        <xsd:enumeration value="p3"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="p4"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="C3BaseRest">
    <xsd:restriction base="C3Base">
        <xsd:enumeration value="r5"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r6"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r7"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

... etc ...
The code above is trying to restrict this block of code:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="c2">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="C2Base"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="c3">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="C3Base"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="C2Base">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="p1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="p2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="p3"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="p4"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="p5"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="C3Base">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="r1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r3"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r4"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r5"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r6"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="r7"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The error is:

**"Type 'CTypeRestric' is not a valid restriction of type 'CType'.
The default binding 'c2' doesn't subsume the default binding 'c2'.
The complex type definition 'CTypeRestric' is not derived by restriction from type definition 'CType'."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c2` attribute in your base type is not of type `C2Base` as it might seem. It actually has an anonymous simple type which is a restriction of `C2Base`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="c2">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="C2Base"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

To derive `CTypeRestrict` your `c2` would have to be a restriction not of `C2Base` but of that anonymous `simpleType` that you defined, which is inaccessible. What I mean is that if your base type was defined like this:

```
<xsd:attribute name="c2" type="c2_type"/>

<xsd:simpleType name="c2_type">
     <xsd:restriction base="C2Base"/> 
</xsd:simpleType>
```

then you *would* be able to create a derivation of the actual type of `c2` by restricting based on `c2_type`. But declaring a simpleType based on `C2BaseRest` which is derived from `C2Base` is not a valid restriction, since the original type of `c2` is not `C2Base` (but the anonymous type derived from it).

*If* you could change the base types, you could declare `c2` like this (as an alternative to having a nested `simpleType` with an empty `restriction`):

```
<xsd:attribute name="c2" type="C2Base"/>
```

Now your `C2BaseRest` actually *would* be a valid restriction of the type of `c2`, and your schema will validate.

The same applies to `c3`.

So, to have the schemas validate, you should change your base schema to:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="c2" type="C2Base"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="c3" type="C3Base"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

It won't be necessary to validate, but you might also want to do the same in the derived one.

```
<xsd:complexType name="CTypeRestric">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="CType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="c2" type="C2BaseRest"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="c3" type="C3BaseRest"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: It was the solution of our problem. Thank you. As you mentioned, although seems that c2 has "restricted" type, actually it is an unexpected "anonymus" type.